# Can't get first array element to print

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Newbie trying to learn how to use d3.js. Been teaching myself JS and tinkering with different libraries the past couple weeks.

script.js

```
var test = d3.select("body").data([1, 2, 3]);

test.enter().append("p").append("test").text(function(d)
{
   return "Hey there... #" + d;
});
```

When I run the HTML file for this, I get this in the body:

index.html:

```
Hey there... #2
Hey there... #3
```

My question is, *why does the first element in my data array not print*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You selected the wrong elements. `d3.select("body").data([1, 2, 3]);` will select all elements with tag name `body` and bind the data to it. There already is one (and only one) `body` element in the document, which will be associated with `1` (in addition, `.select` will always return a set of one element, no matter how many elements could be matched by that selector).

Then `test.enter().append("p")` basically says: For every unassociated data point (`2` and `3`), create a `p` element.

So what you really want is select `p` elements at the beginning:

```
var test = d3.selectAll("p").data([1, 2, 3]);
```

Comment: The `.select()` should be a `.selectAll()`.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff: Thanks, haven't played with d3 lately, forgot about that.